# Luggage storage in Bogota for 4 days

Tags: luggage-storage, colombia, backpacks, venezuela

My girlfriend and I are flying from Europe to Colombia in 2 weeks and after that 2 weeks to Venezuela, we are landing in Bogota with 2 big suitcases, and we have a 4 days trip to Cartagena, for this Cartagena trip  we have a domestic flight, so we would like to take with us our backpacks and leave winter clothes, presents for friends etc in Bogota, since we are coming back 4 days later and stay there for a couple of days more before leaving to Vzla.

Is there any luggage storage service that we can rent for 4 days?

[I have found that we can find some of them that can be rented for 12 hours.](https://eldorado.aero/en/services/baggage-storage/)

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in Bogota, and there is a luggage storage, I've paid   13.000 pesos per bag per 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is luggage storage in the airport with details available [here](https://eldorado.aero/en/services/baggage-storage/).

They have multiple day options:

> When I asked for a few day discount, they said no, but give it a try.

Source: [TripAdvisor Discussion](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294074-i3499-k12354900-Luggage_storage-Bogota.html)